# What does the .shape represent in Python?

Tags: python

I wanted to know what this represents, meaning, what does this tell me:

```
len(array.shape)
```

the *array* being a random np.array

Thank you!

Comment: The numpy documentation, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html#numpy.ndarray.shape, says “Tuple of array dimensions.” Tuples are similar to lists, but immutable: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking for the length of the shape of an array, meaning that you'll get the number of dimensions as a result. A 3D array will have a shape `(x, y, z)`, meaning that `len(array.shape)` will give you the result 3.

Answer (score 0):

The array.shape returns the maximum value in form of *(x,y)* of the the array
And on calculating the length of the array.shape you will be getting the **dimensions** of the array

```py
import numpy as np
a=np.array([1,2,3])
print(len(a.shape))
print(a.shape)
```

The above code will give 1 as output since it is 1D array

```py
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
print(len(a.shape))
print(a.shape)
```

The above code will give 2 as output since it is 2D array.